# How to put spacing between a horizontal and vertical sidebar

Tags: html, css

Hi guys thanks in advance for the help and support!

I am learning to code and apologize in advance for the basic question. I am making a web-page used specifically for me learning to code. I have two sidebars implemented but they overlap causing the top bar to push over to the right how can I correct this? the code is as follows.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 99%
    }
    ul.vertical {
    list=-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: #333;
 width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 }
    li.sidebar {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
    }

    li:last-child {
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: none;
    }
    li a{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px
 text-align center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #111;
    }
    .active {
     background-color: #4CAF50;

    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="#search">search</a></li>
      <li style="float:left"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
    <li style="float:left"><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="vertical">
    <li><a class="active" href="#zero">zero</a></li>
     <li style=" sidebar float:right"><a class="active" href="#one">one</a></li>
      <li style=" sidebar float:right"><a href="#two">two</a></li>
      <li style=" sidebar float:left"><a href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li style="sidebar float:left"><a href="#four">four</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: can you draw what you need ? also style=" sidebar float:right" you should remove sidebar from style

Comment: You should definitely show us a picture or give a better description of what you're trying to do. It's really unclear as the question is written currently. *"I have two sidebars implemented but they overlap causing the top bar to push over to the right how can I correct this?"* How you "correct" it depends on what you want to happen instead, and you didn't mention that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that your reaching out for help, it can sometimes be confusing. But it gets easier as you go on. First off, some of your CSS properties are written wrong. I notice three mistakes highlighted below...

```
ul.vertical {
    list=-style-type: none;
}

ul {
   padding 0; 
}

li a {
     padding: 14px 16px
     text-align center; 
}
```

The second two are missing colon's, as well as a semi colon. And the first one has an added equal sign in the property. You should really structure your code to make it optimal for reading and looking for errors. I noticed that your spacing is very inconsistent. You also added styles in your html document, which is a bad habit to get into when using an external stylesheet already.

In order to add spacing between two divs, you can use the margin property to both the first and second sidebar selector classes. I'll include an example that you can copy the code with and study.

//html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sidebars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="sidebar1">
        <ul>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Search</li>
          <li>Login</li>
          <li>Register</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar2">
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

//css

```
.sidebar1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sidebar2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

As you can see I added 4 digits to my margins, Those four digits from left to right go top-right-bottom-left. So you can see I added 5px of margin on the right for the first sidebar, and 5px on the left for the second. For a net total of 10px of padding.

I hoped this helped you, and gave you a good example of neat and tidy code. :)